# convert Streaming csv data into json data format, programing lang-nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv, sails.js

I am trying to use an API and getting data in (;) semicolon separated csv data.

But demands of my project is, i need data in json format 
Bellow is the code which is giving me csv format raw data.

Programming language used is nodejs
**Can any one help me in this subject**

```
       module.exports = {
    index: function(req,res){

        console.log("Hello welcome!");



    var Semrush = require('semrush-api'); //semrush-api

    var sem = new Semrush({
        apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' || process.env.SemrushApiKey,
        debug: false //optional
    });
    sem.domainRankHistory({
        domain: 'www.seoexplode.com',
        database: 'us'
        }, function(error, results){
            console.log('results \n', results);
            if(error) return 
                console.error(error);
            console.log("There is some error to fetching web traffic on API !");
            console.log("err: ",error);
    });
}
};
```

**Output I received is:**

> Hello welcome!

**Results**

> ```
> Domain;Date;Rank;Organic Keywords;Organic Traffic;OrganicCost;
> Adwords Keywords;Adwords Traffic;Adwords Cost
>
> Domain;20131215;13821033;1;0;0;0;0;0
>
> Domain;20140115;251818;12;1730;36450;0;0;0
>
> Domain;20140215;156507;14;3350;69104;0;0;0
>
> Domain;20140315;70248;24;9899;255415;0;0;0
>
> Domain;20140415;70828;67;9846;256145;0;0;0
>
> Domain;20140515;64925;78;10861;283009;0;0;0
> ```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what kind of JSON data you need to turn this into?

Is your question basically how to turn the CSV-data into JSON?

Comment: Use any CSV module. E.g. [`fast-csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) with `delimiter=';'`

Comment: Hello i need to convert this streaming live data into live streaming json data, this result is achiving in runtime, i was trying to do with **npm module "csvtojson"**  but could not achieved success. suggestion is most welcome, this code is sample code which is returning out as semicolon (;) separated. This is Raw csv data

Comment: Hello folks!! Your Help is most appreciated .